# 0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.24)]

Tags: apt

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 Server LTS on my older Sony laptop. I selected to install LAMP, SSH and utilities.  I am able to ssh into the newly installed system.  However I am having no luck getting `sudo apt-get update` to complete.  I see the following for several minutes:

```
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.24)]
```

Then this comes up on my terminal console:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried several strategies from the postings I saw about other individuals having issues similar to this but none has resolved the problem.

I have even re-installed the system and the issues are still there with the `apt-get`.

Am I missing something or is there a fix for this?

Comment: please check your internet connectivity , it looks like there is some firewall which are restricting resources. i faced this issue.

Comment: I have done the following:jmstein@ubuntuhome:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
jmstein@ubuntuhome:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
jmstein@ubuntuhome:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$

Comment: Here is the output from the iptables command:           sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: I resolved the issue.   I saw that my router had a restriction on port 80 for the ip address defined for my Ubuntu laptop.  I removed this and it appears to be working.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The router had a restriction on port 80 for the IP address defined for the Ubuntu laptop which caused `Unable to connect to [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]` errors when trying to run `sudo apt update` .

Other causes of the same `connection timed out` error message are that the network is down at your update server mirror or at one or more of your other software sources such as PPAs.